# Texture coordinates dupliface UV projection

Tags: texture-coordinates

How do I get the desired texture coordinate projection for duplifaces? I've tried everything and nothing seems to be working.

Here's how it should look: [image]

[image]

This is how mine looks

Comment: I think you should select the parent object in the `object` input of the Texture Coordinates node because right now, it uses the UV of the duplifaces and not the parent's UV

Comment: It doesn't change anything when I set the object to the parent in the texture coordinate node

Comment: Can you give me a link to where you took the first screenshot? I couldn't replicate it either.

Comment: Never mind. I found it

Comment: OK. I think I know what the problem is, give me a few minutes to write the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up your duplifaces correctly, then I think you are doing nothing wrong. The only thing that you may want to take notice at is that the [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html) states that the `From instancer` option works for **Cycles only**.

[image]

So **you need to be in Cycles and view your object in rendered mode** :

[image]
[image]

But just to make sure, this is how you should set this up :

You create two objects, the instancer and the child object. In my case the instancer is an `UV Sphere` and the child is an `Icosphere`. You parent the child to the inscancer with `CTRL` + `P` and you select the instancer and got to the objects tab under `Instancing` (in 2.79- it is called `Duplication`) and select `Faces` :

[image]
[image]

Then you should have the child duplicated all over the parent's faces.

For the material you just need to add the texture to the child. You use the same node tree as your screenshot but you check `From instancer` and you should be able to see the desired result in rendered mode.

Comment: Thanks for the assist, so it doesn't work in eevee? D:

Comment: No it doesn't. For the moment.